Can a function over a domain with holes have a derivative of zero everywhere but fail to be constant?
I've been reviewing some real analysis to prepare for topology and I got myself into a pickle while trying to understand disconnected sets and holes. Here is some reasoning that arrives at a weird result, so I think something is wrong somehwere.
Let $[a,b]\in \mathbb{R} -\{0\}$ where $a>0$ and $b<0$
Consider the function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$f(x) = 1$ if $x>0$  and $-1$ if $x<0$
Is this function differentiable everywhere along it's domain? Since it's domain doesn't contain zero, I don't think we can construct a example where $x\in [a,b]$ and $f' = lim_{h\rightarrow 0}[ \frac{f(x + h)-f(x)}{h}]$ doesn't exist. I think this derivative would be zero everywhere as for any $x \in [a,b]$ we can find an arbitrarily close $y \in [a,b]$ with the same sign, which would mean that eventually $f(x)-f(y) = 0$.
Assuming this function is differentiable everywhere in it's domain, it must be continuous everywhere in it's domain. This is where I realized that something must be wrong with my reasoning, because in class I learned that continuous functions with a derivative of zero everywhere must be constant, but $f$ is not constant.
Please help me find the mistake in my reasoning.

What does $[a,b]$ signify if $a>0$ and $b<0$?

"because in class I learned that continuous functions with a derivative of zero everywhere must be constant" this is only true on connected domains. The general statement is that a function with zero derivative everywhere is locally constant, i.e. it is constant on each component of its domain.

Assume that a high vertical wall is located at $x=0.$ Two mathematicians  are standing on the opposite sides of the wall. Each of them  chooses a constant which defines a function $f(x)$ on their side of the wall. The probability  that they come up with the same value is zero.

The problem in your logic is that "continuous functions with a derivative of zero everywhere must be constant". This is only true in connected domains. For example, in $(- \infty, 0)$, you function is constant, and in $(0, \infty)$, your function is again constant, but the entire function is not constant, since your domain has holes in it.

Providing an effective example, like $f(x) = -1$ if $x<0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ might help clarify the confusion

@Didier I refered to the problem as an example
